# angularjs image base64 show error "Failed to load resource"

Tags: angularjs

if I used this code, it generates error "Failed to load resource", although the image renders correctly.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{image|| 'R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP7//wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='}}">
```

I use the directive ngCloak and ngBind but still showing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely need to use [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) so that the `src` attribute doesn't render before Angular can interpolate the expression.

Comment: Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: Sweet, happy to help.  You should consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.  Cheers!